# Altair: How to use linked brushing on a faceted plot (using .facet)?

Tags: python, altair

I'm trying to create an interactive faceted plot using linked brushing. I don't know if it's because not all observations are present in all conditions, or if it's simply a question of syntax, but it does not seem to work as expected. The main difference with my code and the example given in the documentation is the use of .facet (which I use because the faceting variable is a single column in my dataframe).

The plot generated using the following code (in jupyter, altair v5.1.2) does not interact as expected. If I select points on a facet, a rectangle is automatically drawn on other facets, but the rectangle only delimitates a range of x and y values. I was expecting the corresponding observations to be highlighted. More specifically if observation Z (in my dataset they can be identified using the column 'aa_seq') is part of the selection, I am expecting its corresponding dot in the other conditions/facets to be highlighted. I've also tried hconcat and manually selecting the correct condition for each facet but the output is the same. I appreciate any help, thx!

```
import altair as alt

alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()

brush = alt.selection_interval(resolve='global')

base = alt.Chart(epistat_aa, width=200, height=200).mark_circle().encode(
    x = alt.X("additivity:Q").title('sₓ+sᵧ').scale(domain=(-12, 12), clamp=True),
    y = alt.Y("double_s:Q").title('sₓᵧ').scale(domain=(-15, 15), clamp=True),
    #color=alt.Color('epistatic_score:Q').scale(scheme='redblue'),
    #color=alt.Color('ca_distance:Q').scale(scheme='lighttealblue'),
    color=alt.condition(brush, 'ca_distance:Q', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip=['aa_seq','double_s','additivity','epistatic_score','ca_distance'],
    column="condition:N"
).add_params(
    brush
).configure_mark(
    opacity=0.3
).configure_header(
    title=None
).configure_legend(
    direction='horizontal',
    orient='bottom'
)
```

Tentative faceted plot with linked brushing
[image]